# one screen has multiple components with the same design(reusable component ) using different instances from the same provider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a page with a Navbar containing a number of buttons. When you click on one of the buttons,

```
    NavBarListTile(
                    title: 'Phone Room',
                    icon: Icons.phone_android_rounded,
                    press: () {
                      componentsProv.addComponent(
                        widget: ResizableWidget(
                          width: 643.3199999999999,
                          height: 371,
                          child:  ActiveRoomPhone(
                            key: componentsProv.createKey('Active Room-Phone')!,
                          ),
                        ),
                        label: 'Active Room-Phone',
                      );
                    },
                  )
```

it creates a widget that includes a data grid and has its own provider. I made 3 widgets and each one has a different instance of the same provider using the `family` modifier,

```
 final activeRoomProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose.family<ActiveRoomRepositoryImpl, ValueKey<String>>((ref, key) => ActiveRoomRepositoryImpl(key: key));
```

and I am listening inside the widget using `Consumer`

```
final activeRoomP = ref.watch(activeRoomProvider(key));
```

Therefore, I distinguish between the instances through a key that I give to the provider, as well as to the corresponding widget, but I must communicate between these instances for one provider in UI code for multiple components.

in brief, I need a way to connect between various instances from the same provider. Is there a way to do that